How to clear clipboard history in expo react native
So I needed to get the clipborad content when the app is in foreground then clear the content when the App goes into background, I had some series of try which work as expected except that the clipboard keep the history and even when the App goes into background and i copy another content from another App, after my App come back to foreground it only remember the first content of the clipboard but didn't have the new content which i later copied, So i want to know how i can clear the content of clipboard when the App goes into background so when i copy new content , the old content will not remain.
 useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener('change', nextAppState => {
      if (
        appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
        nextAppState === 'active'
      ) {
        if(Clipboard.hasStringAsync()){
          const getString = async () =>{
            const text = await Clipboard.getStringAsync();
            store.dispatch(updateCheckClipBoard(true))
          }

          getString()
        }
        
      }else{
        store.dispatch(updateCheckClipBoard(false))
      }

      appState.current = nextAppState;

    });

useEffect(() =>{
    const getString = async () =>{
      const text = await Clipboard.getStringAsync();
      setClipboardText(text);
    }

    getString();
  },[])

